# How should this site's chat room be named?

Tags: discussion, chat

Every Stack Exchange site has a dedicated public chat room. That chat room should have a proper topic related name. Like the [Chat of Things](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49682/chat-of-things) for the IoT site or Superuser's [Root Access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access). It's our turn to answer this question for this new site.

What should this site's room be named?

P.S. One suggestion per answer.

---

[Lumenati it is.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71834/lumenati)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I might be too late, but **Lumenati**

Answer (score 6):

**Lumenauts.**

Short and simple

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation:
**Cellar**

Answer (score 2):

**Stroopers**

Reference: https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html#one-stroop-multiple-stroops

Answer (score 1):

How about:

### The Bright Lumen

Answer (score 1):

**ISS**

For International Space Station, or International Stellar Station. The chat room is our hangout amongst the stars while we're not flying through the financial blockchain universe in our little rocket ship.